# Subclassing the Application Class

Tags: android, constructor, android-context, super

In Android when you subclass the `Application` class is it best to intialise variables in the constructor or in `onCreate`?  Or does it make no difference?

Comment: As far as I saw in all examples and tutorials, I would say that it's better to do it on the `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rarely implement a constructor on an Android component, such as an `Activity` or `Application`. Inside of `onCreate()`, after you have called `super.onCreate()`, you can safely use most superclass methods. Hence, the typical pattern is to initialize anything complex in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Would you say therefore that the constructor is relatively obsolete in an Android component?

Comment: @CrimsonChin: Not so much "obsolete" as just not typically useful.